# UICollectionView in a UICollectionViewCell of a bigger UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

So I am developing this store app in swift. Each UICollectionViewCell is a category and it contains a UICollectionView of items to sell. Each category is scrollable horizontally, but the bigger Collection View is scrollable vertically.

Now, the problem is, when I scroll the first category and I scroll down lower, maybe in the 5th category after the one I scrolled to the left, it also scrolls to the left.

Also, when I scroll it to the 6th item horizontally, for example, then scroll down to categories until I can't see it, and scroll up, that category goes back to the first item.

I can't figure out this one. But I think it has something to do with collectionviews refreshing or something. Here is the code for cellForItem:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

    cell.labelCategory.text = self.arrayCategories[indexPath.row].name
    cell.items = self.arrayCategories[indexPath.item].items
    cell.reloadCollection()
    return cell
}
```

am I doing something very wrong? Thanks for your help!

update: as to what I am attempting to do:

I want to show each category vertically. Each category has its collection view which contains items to sell and I can scroll to them horizontally.

Comment: cell.reloadCollection() its not good idea to reload your collection cell inside cellForItemAtIndexPath method.

Comment: hmm.. how about if I use a UITableView instead to store the categories? @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: just update your question with storyboard ui that you build and what kind of output you want so i can easily get you.

Comment: are you use like one collectionview inside one cell you create one tableview ? right ?

Comment: yes @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: ya do it and its easy to manage this thing. and please update your question with what you want at runtime so other stack user also give you solution and suggestion for making that thing.

Comment: Please let me know if you know the answer. I'm in same situation